# SNOWFLAKE insert failing -- Timestamp '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000' is not recognized

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from SQL server to Snowflake environment.
SQL gives output of date as  --06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000'

While inserting this value in snowflake with timestamp(9) as datatype, I am getting this error --
Timestamp '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000' is not recognized

If I am inserting-- '06/28/2016 20:35:06' --> This is getting inserted.

I have tried

1. ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'AUTO';
2. ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MM:SS.FF6';
3. ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'AUTO';
4. 2. ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS.FF6';

Nothing worked as of now.

can someone help ?

Comment: This will sound out there, but have you considered changing your source data to pass in an ambiguous format in the first place? This way you won’t need any of this formatting junk. `:` instead of `.` for milliseconds certainly seems off, but M/D/Y is kind of a garbage format anyway.

Comment: Yes, It was same what was required in snowflake .

Got the answer - ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff6';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use lower case versions of your format string it works for me:

Well, if `mi` is used for minutes, [parameters format](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions) AND the marker for the milliseconds is `:` not `.` in you example data

```
select  '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000' as inp
    ,try_to_timestamp(inp, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff6') as ts1
    ,try_to_timestamp(inp, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff6') as ts1b
    ,try_to_timestamp(inp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS.FF6') as ts2
    ,try_to_timestamp(inp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6') as ts3
    ,try_to_timestamp(inp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6') as ts4
    ;
```

| INP | TS1 | TS1B | TS2 | TS3 | TS4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000 | 2016-06-28 20:35:06.703 | 2016-06-28 20:35:06.703 | null | null | null |

### With Session format:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff6';
select '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000'::timestamp;
```

seems to work for me, albeit still not actually an insert

| '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000'::TIMESTAMP |
| --- |
| 2016-06-28 20:35:06.703 |

### With data insert:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff6';

create table ts_test(ts timestamp_ntz);

insert into ts_test  select '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000';

select * from ts_test;
```

| TS |
| --- |
| 2016-06-28 20:35:06.703 |

this also works for me:

```
insert into ts_test values ('06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000');
```

Comment: I am trying to insert data - If I do like this 

ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss:ff6)';

and then insert , it still shows ""Timestamp '06/28/2016 20:35:06:703000' is not recognized"" . The query you posted works with select but I am trying to insert 1 as of now to rectify the issue and then bulk load

Comment: Select works for me too. But when trying to insert its giving error

Comment: Great thanks a lot. Inserted one row with - ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff6';

Comment: Glad to hear you got there.

Comment: Thanks to you for quick help.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer